# Error while `pod try GooglePlaces`

Tags: ios, curl, cocoapods, macos-sierra

I am trying to get the demo project provided by Google for Places API using the command `pod try GooglePlaces` and `pod try GooglePlacePicker`, but this always fails after few minutes with an error as stated below:

```
Rohans-MacBook-Pro:~ rohan$ pod try GooglePlaces
Updating spec repositories

CocoaPods 1.2.0.beta.1 is available.
To update use: `sudo gem install cocoapods --pre`
[!] This is a test version we'd love you to try.

For more information, see https://blog.cocoapods.org and the CHANGELOG for this version at https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/releases/tag/1.2.0.beta.1


Trying GooglePlaces
[!] /usr/bin/curl -f -L -o /private/var/folders/33/srwyncb13253t9jw7j73v33r0000gn/T/CocoaPods/Try/GooglePlaces/file.tgz https://dl.google.com/dl/cpdc/98bcd61eb763c4a4/GooglePlaces-2.1.1.tar.gz --create-dirs --netrc-optional

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:03:11 --:--:--     0
curl: (56) SSLRead() return error -9806
```

Can someone please help me with figuring out what is going wrong?

**Note:** `pod install`, `pod update`, `pod setup` these commands run properly without any error. I am on macOS Sierra, Xcode 8.1, Cocoapods 1.1.1

Comment: did you delete the pod and podlock file before install ?

Comment: Error 9806 in curl means that the connection was terminated by the server due to a ssl error

Are you behind a proxy server? (Maybe this can cause the error)

Comment: No. I am trying to do `pod try GooglePlcaes` in home folder of my user. I don't think it depends on `Podfile` or `Podfile.lock`. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @DominikVincenz can you please help me with solving the curl error. I have no idea how that works.

Comment: Try to open https://dl.google.com/dl/cpdc/98bcd61eb763c4a4/GooglePlaces-2.1.1.tar.gz in your browser and check if you can download it. If it does not work, you have ssl problems with the google dl-server

Comment: @DominikVincenz hitting this URL in chrome gives me "The web page at https://dl.google.com/dl/cpdc/98bcd61eb763c4a4/GooglePlaces-2.1.1.tar.gz might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address."

Comment: @TheRohanSanap Then you have a connection problem to the google dl-server. This should be a problem with your internet connection. Maybe you can try to connect to you mobile phone hotspot and execute the command with that internet connection

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130466/discussion-between-the-rohan-sanap-and-dominik-vincenz).